# How to restrict a user to enter only particular values in a jpa column?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would like to restrict a user from entering values other than the given set of values into a jpa column.

For example, if I have a table like this..

```
sno sname college_name
----------------------
101 smith Stanford
102 jack  Harvard
103 tiger Stanford
104 scott Harvard
```

and the class..

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer sno;
@Column(name="SNAME", nullable=false)
private String sname;
@Column(name="COLLEGE_NAME", nullable=false)
private String collegeName;

            // setters and getters omitted
}
```

Is there a way, probably using annotations, to restrict the user to enter either **Stanford** or **Harvard** (case sensitive) into the college name.

**Note:** Instead of writing a trigger on the database side, I would want to achieve this via the Java program to save a database call. The above entity is container managed and that `sno`,`sname`,`college_name` are persistence fields, not properties.

Do I have to definitely perform a check before inserting? I am looking for another way?

Thanks in advance. Hope you will reply as soon as possible.

Comment: I think that [@Enumerated](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jpa-enumerated/README.html) is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than be a String you can change the type of collegeName to be an Enum.

Answer (score 2):

Use Enumerated
http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jpa-enumerated/README.html

Btw, I wouldn't store the String values ("Harvard", "Stanford") directly in the DB table. Instead I would use codes (1, 2) and introduce a dictionary table with:

Code ¦ Value
1      Harvard
2      Stanford

Comment: Also is there a way to add regex check before inserting the data into the column?

Comment: @Michał Urbaniak - Your link doesn't works: http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jpa-enumerated/README.html

Answer (score 2):

Enums are a nice way to do it, but you probably can not foresee all universities in the world, so you might also consider using a different table with the known universities, and a many-to-one relation to it.

Ensuring that data is valid should usually be done with bean validation. 
Database triggers or constraints are useful, but are not unique between different database providers.

Regards from Germany,
Thomas